# WordPress: Update User Profile to include author object in ACF user field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

This is an odd situation. I’m trying to make a pseudo like/follow functionality on a membership site using ACF.

I have gotten it to display the liked/followed user from a user object field within the backend. I now need to build a button that I can add to all users profile pages that will allow the user to like/follow that user, which will add to their user field within their own profile page on the frontend and update it all in one go.

Any ideas on how this can be done? I’ve not found anything on my initial searches.

I've tried building out an ACF Form but its not updating the options. I've also tried this code:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
add_action('acf/save_post', 'update_name');
function update_name($current_user) {

  if (get_post_type($current_user) != 'user_follows') {
    return;
  }
    
$field_key = "field_63d0017ab088f";
$value = get_the_author_meta('user_nicename');

update_field( $field_key, $value, $current_user);
}
```

and then firing it with an input submit button:

```
<input type="submit" class="acfef-submit-button acf-button button button-primary" data-state="publish" value="Follow">
```

Sadly this didn't work either.

Anyone have any ideas how I can get this working?

Any help would be great!

Comment: Are you sure that the button triggers the action, have you tested that the update_name function is fired? That's where I'd start if I was trying to fix your example code. But I think I'd probably build something like this using REST API so it would function more like a traditional Like button with no page reload. I'm sure I have done similar things before and have snippets of code that could help you if you wanted try this.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your ACF field setup? i.e. what type of field you're using so I could set up on my install and see if I can help.

Comment: Sure, the field is a user field that shows in all users in the backend. It displays users on the front end in the users own profile properly, just can't get it to "add" a user to the list with a button click (like a follow button sort of thing).

Comment: [link](http://www.designbychris.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/userfield.png) this is the screenshot of the field. Sorry forgot to add it to my last entry.

Comment: Ideally the button will automatically add the profile your on to the user field list in the backend on the user whos looking at the profile (if that makes sense). So that it will then display as part of the list on the front end. I'm sure that there is a way to do this. I feel like its really close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty simple solution that you can tailor to your needs or maybe just help you on your way in how you were originally trying it. I wasn't sure how you were going about it from your original and guessed it could be solved with a simple form using `update_field`. I'd definitely build this with REST API if I was doing it myself. I've just dumped the code below, let me know if it makes sense and/or works for you, if you need I can add comments if required, just updating the `$user_likes` array to update the  field based off the value of the submit button.

I built this on my local install and asuming you are using some variation of the author.php template file.

```
<?php
    $profile_user = get_queried_object();   
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_slug = 'user_' . $current_user->ID;
    $field_key = "field_63d0017ab088f";
    $user_likes = [];

    if(get_field('user_follows', $current_user_slug)){
        $user_likes = get_field('user_follows', $current_user_slug);
    }
        
    if(isset($_POST['follow'])){
        if($_POST['follow'] === 'Unfollow'){
            $key = array_search($profile_user, $user_likes);
            unset($user_likes[$key]);
            update_field($field_key, $user_likes, $current_user_slug);  
        }elseif($_POST['follow'] === 'Follow'){
            $user_likes[] = $profile_user;
            update_field($field_key, $user_likes, $current_user_slug);
        }
    }

    $but_val = 'Follow';
    if (in_array($profile_user, $user_likes)) {
        $but_val = 'Unfollow';
    }
        
?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="follow" value="<?= $but_val; ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: You sir are an absolute genius!!!! Thank you so much!!!